# CSS Inline Block Elements Become Slanted

Tags: html, css

I have some inline block elements inside of a td in a table. The `inline-block` elements parents are a `div`. For some reason, when I have a few dozen `inline-block` elements the elements start to become slanted.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Here is the CSS on my `inline-block` elements:

```
.myclass {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    word-break: break-word;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image: Image of Inline Block Elements appearing in a slanted manner]

When there are only a few elements they display just fine.

Comment: optical illusion ?

Comment: Yep. This isn't a coding thing...it's all optical.

Comment: put a border on each div and you should be able to tell that there is no slanting

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: I can't even see the optical illusion here. Power to those who can.

Comment: Huh it must just be me. I pay close attention to details when building software so maybe it's just me. Anyways, thanks for the feedback everyone.